# Data edit - modal Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with editing data in the bootstrap modal.

The problem is that in the modal, only first record from the database is displayed.

Modal only displays the problem because it retrieves data from 1 record.

Could it show me something wrong with the code, that it only gets 1 record for me?

My code AngularJS:

```
controllersAdmin.controller('linkEdit', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams, $timeout){
    var linkID = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.id = linkID;

  $scope.link = function( link ){
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/admin/links/get/' + linkID,

   }).then(function (response){

    $scope.link = response.data.records;
   },function (error){
    console.log('Blad we wczytywaniu danych');
   });
 }

   $scope.saveChanges = function( link ){
    $http({
      method: 'POST', url: 'api/admin/links/update/', data: {'link' : link}},

      ).then(function (){
        $scope.success = true;

   },function (error){
      console.log('Blad we wczytywaniu danych');

   });
   }
 });

<tr ng-repeat="link in link">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{link.links}}">{{link.links | limitTo:50}}...</a></td>

        <td>{{ link.login }}</td>
        <td>{{link.password}}</td>
        <td>{{link.date}}</td>
        <td>

          <button ng-click="deleteLink(link, $index)" class="btn btn-danger">&times;</button>

       <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edtlnk(link)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
       <div class="modal fade" id="edit-data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <form method="POST" name="editlinke" role="form" ng-submit="saveChanges( link )">

                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Item</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="container">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="link.login">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="link.password">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="link.links">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: The model window put in outside the table.Now the model inside the ng-repeat so only showing last record.

Comment: Can you show how it should look like?